# GraphQL: Prevent a DDOS attack on a public GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql, cloudflare, ddos

I have a public GraphQL API that my web app, iOS apps, and Android apps all use to communicate with my database. I want to promote the API to allow developers to take advantage of it, but I'm afraid of DDOS attacks on the API taking down the entire application.

In 2018, what's the best way to protect a public GraphQL API from denial of service? Ideally, I'd like to use something like CloudFlare to enforce a rate limit, and temp ban IP addresses that are requesting too much, too frequently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can totally use Cloudflare for this (source: I work for Cloudflare). We don't cache GraphQL but layer 3/4 protection and rate limiting should work just fine.

Comment: Cool! Is there any documentation you could point me to to help get this set up? Thanks!

Comment: It should just work 'out of the box' for any Orange clouded (proxied) record. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/categories/200275218-Getting-Started if you run into difficulties feel free to ask here or in the community foru,s.

Comment: The link is dead.  There is no answer to this question anymore.